# Activity with ViewPager and Fragment. How to replace a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

i have a MainActivity with tab bar and when i click on the icon the corresponding fragment show in the viewPager.
I have a trouble on how it works because i can't find where in the code I switch from a fragment to another.

```
package soccerinformations;

import allLibrariesIneed;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private int[] tabIcons = {
        R.drawable.soccerball,
        R.drawable.zoom,
        R.drawable.oldpaper,
        R.drawable.moneyhand
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    setupTabIcons();
}

private void setupTabIcons() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new MatchFragment(), "SOCCERBALL");
    adapter.addFrag(new StatisticheFragment(), "ZOOM");
    adapter.addFrag(new SchedinaFragment(), "OLDPAPER");
    adapter.addFrag(new ContoFragment(), "MONEYHAND");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

}

I have a fragment Match_Fragment and this is the code:

```
public class MatchFragment extends Fragment{

private View rootView;
private String nazione, categoria, homeTeam, guestTeam;
private String[] arrayNazione, arrayCategoria, arrayTeam;
private Spinner spinnerNazione, spinnerCategoria, spinnerHomeTeam, spinnerGuestTeam;
private Button buttonShow;

public MatchFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_match, container, false);

    buttonShow = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);

    buttonShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            //HERE I WANT REPLACE THIS FRAGMENT WITH A NEW BLANK FRAGMENT
            new BlankFragment(); 

        }
    });


    return rootView;
}
```

}

When I click on the buttonShow i want a new fragment instead the current. How it's possible?

Comment: why you want show blank fragment or you mean nested fragment at this point

Comment: blank fragment is only for test. I need a fragment with a layout defined in .xml file (in this example i call this fragment "BlankFragment")

Comment: please check this example https://github.com/saik0/AndroidExamples/tree/master/NestedPager